# What does stall mean in AppDynamics Pro?

Tags: appdynamics

I wonder what stall means in AppDynamics Pro. Can you give an example which Appdynamics Pro application name that situation as Stall?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition can be found in AppDynamics docs: [Slow and Stalled Transactions](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO39/Troubleshoot+Slow+Response+Times#TroubleshootSlowResponseTimes-SlowandStalledTransactions)

> By default AppDynamics considers a slow transaction one that lasts longer than 3 times the standard deviation for the last two hours, a very slow transaction 4 times the standard deviation for the last two hours, and a stalled transaction one that lasts longer than 300 deviations above the average for the last two hours.

Of course, you can modify the default rules by providing your own: [Configure Thresholds](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO39/Configure+Thresholds)